# Is cronjob extra email notification normal?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, daemon

I am working out some cronjobs on ubuntu lucid. I've successfully got the cronjob that:

1. runs a shell script
2. the shell script runs a curl -X GET request on an API endpoint
3. the API sends an email from the website.

However, i'm also getting an additional email per cron run from the Cron Daemon with the output from the curl request, like this:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Is it normal to be emailed with the contents of the shell script output like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected behavior of cron to send any output (stdout alt. stderr) as an e-mail.

In your case I guess you will want to call curl with the flags --silent and --show-error.